# What do square brackets around an identifier in VB.NET signify? 

Tags: vb.net, syntax

I'm quite familiar with VB and .NET in general, but I just ran across this code:

```
Me.[GetType]()
```

What is the purpose of the brackets around `GetType`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The square brackets are used to tell the compiler that he should interpret it as a type, even if it would be a keyword. But your example should be the same as `Me.GetType()`.

You could use it for example for Enums.

Example-Enum:

```
Enum Colors
    Red
    Green
    Blue
    Yellow
End Enum 'Colors

Dim colors = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(Colors))
For Each c In colors
   Console.WriteLine(c)
Next
```

That wouldn't compile normally:

```
Enum.GetValues(GetType(Colors)) 'because Enum is a keyword'
```

Comment: Oh okay, so it's the same as @variable in C#. Thanks!

Comment: In VB6 you could use `[ ]` to create `Enum` values with spaces. I wonder if `VB.NET` is the same way too.

Comment: No you cannot add spaces to an enum's value. read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458257/how-to-have-enum-values-with-spaces Apart from the suggestion to use `EnumMemberAttribute` you could also use a `Dictionary(Of String, EnumType)` instead where the key is a "friendly" name and the value is the enum.

Comment: In general, the square brackets means "don't treat this as a keyword". For example, this method declaration won't compile "Sub Masquerade(ByVal as As String)"; but this will compile "Sub Masquerade(ByVal [as] As String)" and you can use the variable "[as]" in the body of the method.

Comment: You wrote: *"...interpret it as a type"*. I think *"...interpret it as an **identifier**"* would be more precise. In the OP's example, `GetType` is a method name, not a type.