# Difference between [Byte] and byte()

Tags: arrays, vb.net, syntax

I am working with vb.net
I noitce that there are somtimes :

```
Dim broadcastBytes As Byte()
```

and

```
Dim broadcastBytes As [Byte]
```

Is there a diffrence or its just a syntax ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do square brackets around an identifier in VB.NET signify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413343/what-do-square-brackets-around-an-identifier-in-vb-net-signify)

Comment: I think that the answers in this post are  betters and detailed

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a difference:

`Dim broadcastBytes As Byte()` ➔ Declares the variable as a [Byte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/byte-data-type) - [Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/):

`Dim broadcastBytes As [Byte]` ➔ Here `[Byte]` is just the datatype [Byte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/byte-data-type), but declared with square brackets, which is actually not required here.

(see here: [What do square brackets around an identifier in VB.NET signify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413343/what-do-square-brackets-around-an-identifier-in-vb-net-signify) )

Answer (score 1):

MatSnow already answered your immediate question, let me add a few more cases you might encounter for completeness.

Note, in particular, that `New Byte()` can mean either (a) a new byte or (b) a new byte array, depending on whether it is followed by `{...}` nor not.

```
' All examples assume Option Strict and Option Infer On (as it should be)

Dim b As Byte               ' uninitialized Byte variable

Dim b As Byte()             ' uninitialized Byte-Array (Nothing)
Dim b() As Byte             ' same as above, legacy notation

Dim b As New Byte()         ' initialized Byte variable (0), explicitly calling the default constructor
Dim b As Byte = New Byte()  ' same as above
Dim b = New Byte()          ' same as above, with type inference
Dim b As Byte = 0           ' same as above, initialized with a literal
Dim b = CByte(0)            ' same as above, with type inference

Dim b As New Byte()  {}     ' initialized Byte-Array (not Nothing, zero elements)
Dim b As New Byte()  {1, 2} ' initialized Byte-Array (two elements)
Dim b = New Byte()  {1, 2}  ' same as above, with type inference
```

In all of these cases, `Byte` can be replaced by `[Byte]` without changing anything.